# Scala reflection: Why does getMethods return private vals defined in superclass?

Tags: scala, reflection

Code below defines a trait `T` with a private val `someVal` and an anonymous class extending `T`. If we call `getMethods` from the instance of the anonymous class, `someVal` is listed as a public method:

```
scala> trait T { private val someVal = 3 }
defined trait T

scala> new T {}.getClass.getMethods.apply(0)
res2: java.lang.reflect.Method = public int $anon$1.$line6$$read$T$$someVal()
```

Of course `someVal` isn't accessible in this subclass, but why is it even in the return of `getMethods`, as public?

Comment: Reflection is rarely the better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trait`s compile to `interfaces`, because they need multiple-inheritance. But interfaces can have neither fields nor non-`public` members. Therefore, a field becomes a pair of `public` accessors, mangled by the trait's name, and the compiler is tasked with placing the field into all subclasses and implementing the accessors. Any methods on `T` trying to access `someVal` go through the getter, and the `static` `$init$` function, which contains the constructor code, uses the setter to set it to `3`. If your `val` were declared `public`, then the name of the getter would be demangled to just `someVal`, and external code would use that, and if it were also `var`, the setter would demangle to `someVal_=`, which subsequently mangles to `someVal_$eq`. The horribly long mangled names are pretty much enough to keep anyone from using them, anyway, and it's only relevant when doing Java interop.